# Создание временных файлов в Гугл тестах

Tags: c++, юнит-тесты, boost, c++14, google-test

Мне надо протестировать аналог утилиты tree, используя гугл тесты, boost и C++ 14. Для этого, естественно, нужно создать временные директории с файлами. Я умею создавать временную директорию, но как создать временной файл (так, чтобы ему можно было указывать имя, адресс). Я пробовал через `tmpnam`, но получал ошибку `bus error 10`, по непонятной мне причине:

```
class TreeTestCase : public ::testing::Test {
public:

    path p;
    std::string testFile;

    TreeTestCase() {
        this->p = current_path();
        this->p += "/my_tmp";
        create_directory(p);
        testFile = std::tmpnam("my_tmp/testFileLongNameToBeFound.txt");
    }

    ~TreeTestCase() {
        remove_all(this->p);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы передаете в tmpnam() константу, а не `char` массив, который она должна заполнить, вот она и валится.

И вообще, это устаревшая функция, вы должны были получить warning при компиляции (по крайней мере в gcc/g++).

Лучше посмотрите  [man tempnam](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/tempnam.3.html) и пользуйтесь ей.